# crystal oscillator output

Tags: oscillator, pll

I have seen the crystal oscillator output in the oscilloscope and it looks something similar to a sine wave (at least nothing similar to a square wave and with a hard to calculate duty cycle)!

So how does a type 1 phase frequency detector (the xor gate) functions with such a reference signal from the crystal oscillator as one of its input?

Comment: Can you tell us what the frequency of the oscillator is, please? And also the bandwidth of the scope, and what type of probe (10x or 1x) that you're using?

Comment: A picture of the scope trace would be helpful too.

Comment: And the oscillator schematic.

Comment: I do not exactly remember the details but I guess it was Agilent InfiniiVision 6000 X-Series oscilloscopes. My xtal was at 12Mhz. I did an auto tune to check the signal. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Using auto-set might have been your problem. Try it again, setting the timebase manually.

Comment: Are you looking at the output signal from a crystal oscillator or one of the signals on the pins of a crystal itself?

Comment: I connected a probe to the external crystal oscillator pin and checked its waveform on oscilloscope. it has a period of 12MHz which I do expect but it looks like a sort of sine wave.

Comment: There's no such thing as a period of 12MHz. There's a frequency of 12MHz, and its period is its reciprocal: 83.3ns.  But, I was trying to determine whether what you're probing is a crystal or a crystal oscillator. No insult intended, but do you know the difference between them?

Answer (score 3):

Some oscillators, particularly crystal VCOs, produce a sine wave or clipped sine wave output. For example, [these](http://www.ecsxtal.com/store/pdf/vc_txo_35sm.pdf).

You would not likely get good results using a digital phase detector on an analog signal, so you would likely want to use a comparator to turn it into a digital signal.